# python pandas df: adding to one column depending on the value in that row in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like:

```
    a   b   c   d
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0
2   1   292 0   0
3   0   500 1   406
4   1   335 0   0
```

I would like to find the sum of column b where a=1 for that row. So in my example I would want rows 2 and 4 added (just column b), but not row 3. If it makes any difference, there are only 0s and 1s. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.loc`

```
>>> df.loc[df.a==1, 'b'].sum()
627
```

You can review the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) for indexing and selecting data.